# Как достать path из svg с помощью BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер, requests, beautiful-soup

Осуществляю парсинг сайта, который показывает погоду: https://www.foreca.ru/Russia/Moscow
Все, что нужно достал, но не получается достать направление ветра
По факту, зацепиться не за что, кроме как залезть в `<svg>`, там найти `<path>` с иконками и сравнивать направления

---

Структура сайта, где иконки с ветром такая (каждая иконка - `<path>`):

```
<div id="meteogram">
    <svg height="330" version="1.1" width="626" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"...>
        <path style="" fill="#88cc4f" stroke="#88cc4f" d="M26,307.5H32V310.5L38,306L32,301.5V304.5H26V307.5" transform="matrix(0,-1,1,0,-274,338)"></path>
```

---

Мне нужно достать все `<path>`, но когда я запускаю `wind_route = soup.find("div", class_="meteogram")` мне возвращается только `<div id="meteogram"></div>`. Может, содержимое этого блока генерируется динамически и нужно использовать селениум?

---

Как достать все `<path>`, либо же можно спарсить направление ветра как-то по другому через foreca?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Посмотрел как формируется график на сайте, хоть вы и видите там `svg`, но он рендерится при загрузке сайта, а для этого нужен движок javascript и все-равно неудобно будет работать с svg :) Но есть решение лучше

Сами же данные находятся в куске `javascript` - список объектов, где поле `ws` соответствует значению стрелки, а `wd` градус наклона стрелки:

```js
var mgdata = [{d:'пн', di: 0, dl: 'Понедельник', dt: '9.8.', hi: '21:00', h: '21', s: 'n000', r: 0.00, rl: 0.00, rs: 0.00, wx: 'Ясно', ws: 2, wd: 45, t: 24}, ...
```

Шаги:

1. Извлечь значение `mgdata` из кода javascript
2. Вытащить данные для парсинга

   1. Используем регулярное выражение
   2. Для удобства преобразовываем данные в питоничьи данные, но есть проблема с ключами словаря, в js их можно без кавычек оформить, а в питоне кавычки потребуются
   3. Сделаем функция препроцесса, чтобы добавить кавычки, тогда `ast.literal_eval` сможет распарсить строку и получим список из словарей
3. Вывести результат парсинга

[Решение:](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/6d945956e243889083e32480bb2f5a2d7d730889/html_parsing/www_foreca_ru__Russia__Moscow.py)

```
import ast
import re

import requests


def preprocess_js(text: str) -> str:
    return re.sub(r'(\w+):', r'"\1":', text)


rs = requests.get('https://www.foreca.ru/Russia/Moscow')

m = re.search(r'var mgdata = (.+);', rs.text)
js_text = m.group(1)
print(js_text)
# [{d:'пн', di: 0, dl: 'Понедельник', dt: '9.8.', hi: '21:00', h: '21', s: 'n000', r: 0.00, rl: 0.00, rs: 0.00, wx: ...

js_text = preprocess_js(js_text)
print(js_text)
# [{"d":'пн', "di": 0, "dl": 'Понедельник', "dt": '9.8.', "hi": '"21":00', "h": '21', "s": 'n000', "r": 0.00, "rl" ...

items = ast.literal_eval(js_text)
for x in items:
    print(x['dl'], x['ws'], x['wd'])
```

Результат:

```
Понедельник 2 45
Вторник 2 45
Вторник 2 90
Вторник 3 135
Вторник 3 180
...
Суббота 3 270
Суббота 2 315
Суббота 2 270
Суббота 2 225
Воскресенье 2 225
```